# Should I provide `iterator` type of an unmodifiable container?

Tags: c++, stl, container-data-type

I'm writing a class which is unmodifiable from outside. It is not 'immutable' since it modifies the contents inside.

I want it to be a `Container`-interface-compliant container; it can't be `Container` anyway since it doesn't have a default constructor.

What i'm wondering is, "Should I provide `iterator`?."

The easiest way is to set `iterator` to be the same with `const_iterator`, but I found that lots of people try to iterate a container through `iterator`, not `const_iterator` even if they don't modify the value while iterating.

Will it be meaningful providing `iterator` which can't modify the value?

Comment: You are allowed to define a `const_iterator` and not an `iterator`, therefore they have no choice to use anything but the `const` version.

Comment: I think you should provide an `iterator` that can't modify the value. People generally expect `C<T>::iterator` to exist for any container template `C` (and for `C<T>::begin()` and `C<T>::end()` to return a value of that type). Also `std::set` does this.

Comment: `std::set` happily provides an iterator that's identical to its const iterator, and people seem to cope with it just fine.

Comment: How did I not remember set? Feeling miserable :( THX everyone!!!